# How to get all paper which cites a paper from Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I want to find all paper wich cites a specific paper(e.g On Random Graphs have been cited 4531 times)

```
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=3057989108594026226&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=zh-CN
```

To be specific, I want the titles and cite numbers of all those papers
I can do the parsing, but I don't know how to get all result html, because google only display  10 paper on one page. So I want a way to download all the result pages.

Comment: Did you find anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Scholar seems to lack a public API.

With some searching, I found [scholar.py](http://www.icir.org/christian/scholar.html), which claims to implement a querier and parser for Google Scholar's output.

Its [code on Github](https://github.com/ckreibich/scholar.py) was updated several days ago, so I suppose that it is still working well right now.